# Detect last cell in full page UICell UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a checkout flow using a UICollectionViewController and a full page UICell. After the last cell(the last item) is displayed I want to add a summary page of all the items that have been added to the shopping cart along with a total price. I tried to check if the last item = itemsArray.count - 1 however it keeps printing "last item" in the cell before last. Also in the last cell, it prints "not last".

```swift
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, PostCellDelegate {

    var totalPrice = Float()

    private var hiddenRows = Set<Int>()

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PostCell

        cell.finalLabel.text = String(totalPrice)
        cell.delegate = self

        let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.set(name: item.name, brand: item.brand, price: item.price)

        if indexPath.row == itemsArr.count - 1 {
            print("last item")
        }else {
            print("not last")
        }
        if hiddenRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.myButton.isHidden = true
            cell.removeButton.isHidden = false
        }else{
            cell.removeButton.isHidden = true
            cell.myButton.isHidden = false
        }
        cell.finalLabel.text = String(totalPrice)
            return cell
        }

    @objc func addTapped(cell: PostCell) {

        guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)  else {return}
        hiddenRows.insert(indexPath.row)
        cell.removeButton.isHidden = false
        let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
        print(item.price)
        totalPrice += Float(item.price) ?? 0
        cell.finalLabel.text = String(totalPrice)
    }


    @objc func removeButtonTapped(cell: PostCell) {

        guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)  else {return}
        hiddenRows.insert(indexPath.row)
        cell.myButton.isHidden = false
        let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
        totalPrice -= Float(item.price) ?? 0
        cell.finalLabel.text = String(totalPrice)
    }
}



protocol PostCellDelegate {
    func removeButtonTapped(cell: PostCell)
    func addTapped(cell: PostCell)
    func didPressButton(_ tag: Int)
}

class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var delegate: PostCellDelegate?

    func set(name: String, brand: String, price: String){
        nameLabel.text = name
        brandLabel.text = brand
        priceLabel.text = price
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.removeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(subButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        setupCellConstraints()
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didPressButton(sender.tag)
    }


    @objc func addButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
        self.delegate?.addTapped(cell: self)
        sender.isHidden = true
    }


    @objc func subButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
        self.delegate?.removeButtonTapped(cell: self)
        sender.isHidden = true 
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that instead of having a single cell class that does dual duty, have two cell classes, one for most of the cells and a separate class for the summary cell. Then in your `cellForItemAt` method, return one or the other cells. This is a better design, and it will also help you to clarify your logic, which could result in making it easier for you to find bugs and solutions for the bugs.

Comment: so if I create a different Summary cell, how will I clarify which one should be shown inside of cellForItemAt?

Comment: You can put the special summary cell in a different section. That way in `cellForItem` you can look at the section on the index path and show a different cell for section 2.

Comment: It keeps giving me the incorrect indexPath as soon as I begin to scroll. I tried indexPath.row == itemsArr.count - 1 and I also tried if indexPath.row == itemsArr.last. At this point I am thinking of just adding a button at the last indexPath but I cannot get the collectionView to recognize the last cell in the array.